# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Tags: base-de-datos, django, postgresql, utf-8

estoy haciendo una conexión con django y postgre, todo funcionaba bien hasta que pgadmin4 se actualizo a la versión  7.6. he verificado la decodificación en la base de datos, no hay datos dentro de esta misma que compliquen la lectura, las versiones de pip, django y postgre son las ultimas, también lo intente con versiones anteriores, de igual manera con pgadmin4, verifique las bibliotecas, modifique el archivo postgresql.conf y tanto la bd como el código del proyecto tienen los parámetros de UTF-8 y aún así me dice error de decodificación

Comment: [¿Mismo caso?](/q/419978)